# Angular-CLI with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I've created an SPA Angular-CLI .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017 by:

```
dotnet new angular -o testApp
```

I can build and run it normally by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>. In that case:

- Does `webpack-dev-server` serves the app? In my opinion `webpack-dev-server` is not used here since Kestrel comes into play. However, since webpack is running under the hood there are some bundles that are being created. Here is the HTTP response:

  ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>angular_cli</title>
     <base href="/">

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  The problem is I cannot find any of these bundles inside the application. Where are they? An explanation would be to exist in the memory, however that requires `webpack-dev-server` and my assumption is it is not launched! So, **what exactly does it happen**?
- By trying

  ```
  ng serve
  ```

  which enables the app to be served by `webpack-dev-server`, I cannot 
  communicate with .NET server part. So, **what's the point of using ng serve** if 
  not being able to fully test the application including the back end part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give an update on this.

### For ASP.NET Core 2.1 or 2.0 with new template package

ASP.NET Core 2.1 (preview as the moment of writing) ships with updated angular templates which are available in 2.1 and resides in `Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates` package.

On ASP.NET Core 2.1 its installed with the .NET Core SDK. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Or it can be installed manually via

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0
```

or

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::*
```

to grab the latest version. The updated templates are based on Angular Cli and use the `app.UseSpa(..:)` call whereas the old middleware used Webpack.

### For ASP.NET Core 2.0

The old Angular SPA Template was based on [JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) which were shipped with ASP.NET Core up to version 2.0 or by running `dotnet new -i "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*"`. See [Available templates for dotnet new](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new).

For ASP.NET Core 2.0 this is done by the WebpackDev middleware (see the `app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(...)` call in your Startup.cs.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseBrowserLink();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
    {
        HotModuleReplacement = true
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

it will use the webpack.config.js / webpack.config.vendor.js to build the files on startup or when it changes.

Comment: There is no WebpackDevMiddleWare...
`app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });`

Comment: There used to be unless they changed it. Gotta look what the UseSpa but there have been  [hints that they changed it](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1231#issuecomment-363802889) so its probably that already, but I didn't update my existing projects yet to it. 4-5 moths ago the templates generated `UseWebpackDevMiddleware`

Comment: Are you by chance using ASP.NET Core 2.1 preview? I just updated my templates and created an new project with `dotnet new angular -o testApp` and it still creates a template using `UseWebpackDevMiddleware`

Comment: It is true that I have installed .NET Core SDK 2.1.4. So, do you have any explanation for that case?

Comment: The SDK version isn't that much of important as its not tied to the .NET Core versioning. The version of the Runtime and if its ASP.NET Core 2.1 would be more interesting (i.e. if one shipped with preview editions of VS). Anyways `UseSpa` is from SpaServices which was also used for the `UseWebpackDevMiddleware`  see https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/2.1.0-preview2-final/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L29 so its that which bundles and serves the files and does hot module replacement as mentioned in the issue

Comment: But what I can tell you, the `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` used nodejs and the webpack-dev-server under the hood. Guess now it uses the angular cli equivalents, since thats whats hinted in that issue I linked earlier. The angular stuff is evolving pretty fast, that its hard to follow up :P

Comment: Just in case you're interested, I've updated the question after figuring out why I didn't got the new template on .NET Core 2.0 SDK (and instructions how to get it w/o upgrading to .NET Core 2.1 preview)