# Using both Angular 4 and ASP.NET Core MVC Razor for certain views based on the route

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a project built in ASP.NET Core MVC.  Using the built in identity functionality.  I would like to serve certain views using angular 4 and certain ones using Razor, depending on the functionality required and the migration.  For example I have a schedule route and would like anything under `/Schedule` to be loaded using Angular, as a result loading the `schedule.component.html`.

I have attempted by installing Angular under a `ClientApp` folder under wwwroot. I have an `index.html` that loads the dependencies, this works however I am unsure of how to load the schedule component when using the schedule root.

Will appreciate any help thanks.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<script src="ClientApp/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="ClientApp/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="ClientApp/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="ClientApp/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app')
        .then(
        function () { console.log('started application'); },
        function (err) { console.log('error starting application'); 
console.log(err); });
</script>
</head>
<app-root>Loading..</app-root>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too avoid confusion in future please stop using the outdated term "MVC6". There is no such version anymore and it was only used for a firm time before the preview releases. The version numbering for ASP.NET Core was reset and started with 1.0 and at the time of the writing has reached the version 2.1. It's imply called "ASP.NET Core MVC" (up to 2.1)  and "ASP.NET MVC" (up to version 5.2) for the old legacy framework. Reasons were that MVC6 suggested its an follow up of MVC5 which is not the case. ASP.NET Core is a **complete rewrite** and **incompatible** with ASP.NET

Comment: @Tseng Noted. Thanks, now that the question avoids confusion are you able to assist?

Comment: Can just provide an opinion, no answer though: Wouldn't recommend neither trying to serve the angular part yourself nor trying to mix angular with mvc views. Angular is for SPA (Single Page Application, means its loaded once and then everything else happens in browser which is in contrast to Razor views which are rendered on the server and each time a new request is required), otherwise your app will be reinitialized every time you switch between razor view route and angular route.

Comment: I'd recommend to stay with the default angular templates. Also upgrade to the latest tempaltes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49904569/455493) for whats different as the new angular templates are based on angular cli in contrast to the old devwebpack based tempaltes. They come preconfigured with server-side rendering and more important with application bundling, where all the angular files are bundled into a single file for loading performance

Comment: Ok thanks, is it possible to serve a portion of the application in angular, for example, asp-core handles the login and redirects them to the home razor view, then they click a link, that takes them to the angular route (A different Project) and then this eventually redirects back, as an approach to start migrating certain sections of the webapp into angular?